# Dumb-witted meaning in context

Tags: meaning

What does this word mean? I heard this in the following sentence:

> He is a dumb-witted. He never speaks.

Comment: Perhaps you misheard? This sentence is ungrammatical, and I have never heard the expression "dumb-witted". A fairly common expression is "dim-witted", which is an adjective. So maybe it was "He is dim-witted" or "He is a dim-witted person"?

Comment: No, it's in the Godfather. @akedrou

Comment: See also: [Eggcorn Forum / "dumb-witted" and "dum witted" for "dim-witted"](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=2086). Also notes that the common usage is *dim-witted* for the adjective, and *dimwit* for the noun. -- The fact that you heard it as "He is a dumb-witted." makes me wonder where you heard it and/or who said it.

Comment: Cool, that's fascinating! @DamkerngT. Though, the given sentence remains ungrammatical. It's probably meant to be "He is dumb-witted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, it means foolish + sluggish. I tried to find the entry in routine dictionaries I refer but could not.

However, [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dumbwit) mentions it (note that it doesn't use the hyphen)

> *Someone who is really stupid or foolish*

---

The term is used in [the Godfather](http://www.jgeoff.com/godfather/gf2/transcript/gf2transcript.html)

> All my respect DON CICCIO. DON CICCIO you killed my husband because he wouldn't give into you. And his oldest son PAOLO -- because he swore revenge. But VITO is only nine. And ***dumb-witted***, He never speaks.

Comment: Interesting. Looking through some ngram data, it looks like it's just a misuse, where because "dim-witted" means "dumb" people assume the expression is "dumb-witted" and say it like that. It definitely has been used enough to be an expression itself and has been around forever, though I'd never heard it before!

Comment: @MaulikV I think the spelling of *give into* is strange.

Comment: Nice catch, MaulikV. Indeed I come across the phrase while re-watching the Godfather movie. It appeared in subtitles. I presume the phrase is very informal...